# How to compute exact width added by \left. \right

Tags: lengths

I have defined macros to produce resizable brackets that also work across line breaks.
This necessitated the use of and additional set of `\left.` and `\right.` which add a bit of horizontal space.

Now, when I attempt to remove the additional space by computing its size `\settowidth{\KernAmount}{$\left.\right.$}`, I find I need to add a `17%` fudge factor to get things to be close, so obviously I am not doing this computation correctly.

```
\newdimen{\KernAmount}%
\newcommand*{\BracKern}{%
    \settowidth{\KernAmount}{$\left.\right.$}%
    \kern-1.17\KernAmount%
}%
```

Below is the comparison of the output with the normal `\left...\right` and that of the `\bracc` with the `\kern` with the `17%` adjustment applied:

[image]

### Question:

What is the proper method to adjust for the additional horizontal spacing resulting from the `\left.`, `\right.`?

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newdimen{\KernAmount}%
\newcommand*{\BracKern}{%
    \settowidth{\KernAmount}{$\left.\right.$}%
    \kern-1.17\KernAmount%
}%

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@Brac}[3]{% #1,#3 = left/right bracket type
    \ensuremath{%
        \left#1\vphantom{#2}\right.% left bracket
        \BracKern%
        #2%  content
        \BracKern%
        \left.\vphantom{#2}\right#3% right bracket
    }%
}%
\newcommand{\bracr}[1]{\@Brac{(}{#1}{)}}%   round brackets
\newcommand{\bracc}[1]{\@Brac{\{}{#1}{\}}}% curly bracktes
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent
Comparrison of using \verb|\left\{ ...\right\}| and \verb|\bracc{}|:
\begin{align*}
    \left\{x = \frac{1}{2} \right\}\\
    \bracc{x = \frac{1}{2} }
\end{align*}
%
As we can see in the following, the \verb|\bracr| wraps around lines: 
$\bracr{x^{-1} + x^{-2} + x^{-3} +x^{-4} + x^{-5} + \cdots }$
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\nulldelimiterspace`?

Comment: Yes, `\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace` should do (also with `\left`).

Comment: @egreg: Seems to need same fudge factor: '2.34\nulldelimiterspace'

Comment: Related Question: [Easily change behavior of \DeclarePairedDelimiter](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94410/easily-change-behavior-of-declarepaireddelimiter).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The correct space to be removed is `\nulldelimiterspace`; here's a way that also avoids the additional space inserted by `\left` and `\right`:

```
\newcommand{\BracKern}{\kern-\nulldelimiterspace}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@Brac}[3]{% #1,#3 = left/right bracket type
        \mathopen{\left#1\vphantom{#2}\BracKern\right.}% left bracket
        #2%  content
        \mathclose{\left.\BracKern\vphantom{#2}\right#3}% right bracket
}
\newcommand{\bracr}[1]{\@Brac{(}{#1}{)}}%   round brackets
\newcommand{\bracc}[1]{\@Brac{\{}{#1}{\}}}% curly bracktes
\makeatother
```

<sub>(I've removed `\ensuremath`, of course.)</sub>