# How to color delimiters

Tags: color, delimiters

I have some special delimiters that I want to add to a glossary, those get hyperlinks and colors etc.
However when i want to use those delimiters, using `\left`, `\right` and `\middle` becomes impossible.
I think with the following question fixed I can create my hyperlinked delimiters:

How to color delimiters:

As a minimal working example I have:

```
$\left\textcolor{red}{(}a\right)$
```

What i would like to have is (Created without `\left` `\right`):

[image: Color]

This gets the error: `! Missing delimiter (. inserted).`

---

Trying this :

```
$\textcolor{red}{\left(}a\right)$
```

results in `! Extra }, or forgotten \right.`

Who can help me?

Answer (score 13):

use it this way:

```
$\color{red}\left(\normalcolor a\right)$
```

or

```
$\textcolor{red}{\big(} a\big)$
```

There a `\big`, `\bigg`, `\Big`, and `\Bigg`

Comment: this will not work if the current color is not the \normalcolor. And as I want to use this in a command, this will not work for me. And put this in a hyperlink will not work with this solution.

Comment: then you can only use `\big` et al (see edit).

Comment: However, i do not want the delimiters to be big :)
They should fit, that is why I want to use \left and \right

Answer (score 11):

Here is macro that can easily be extended to different styles of brackets:

[image]

## Notes:

- As egreg pointed out one should use adjust the horizontal spacing via `nulldelimiterspace`. More details on this are at [How to compute exact width added by \left. \right](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54023/how-to-compute-exact-width-added-by-left-right).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\BracKern}{\kern-\nulldelimiterspace}
\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\@Brac}[3]{% #1,#3 = left/right bracket type           
        \mathopen{\color{red}\left#1\vphantom{#2}\BracKern\right.}% left bracket
        #2%  content
        \mathclose{\left.\BracKern\vphantom{#2}\right#3}% right bracket
    }
    \newcommand{\bracr}[1]{\@Brac{(}{#1}{)}}%
    \newcommand{\bracs}[1]{\@Brac{[}{#1}{]}}%
    \newcommand{\bracc}[1]{\@Brac{\{}{#1}{\}}}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    $\bracr{a}$  $\displaystyle\bracr{\frac{1}{2}}$
    $\bracs{a}$  $\displaystyle\bracs{\frac{1}{2}}$
    $\bracc{a}$  $\displaystyle\bracc{\frac{1}{2}}$
\end{document}
```