# Defining a macro for "real" colored delimiters

Tags: math-mode, macros, symbols, color, delimiters

I recently looked up [J. van Hoorn's question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62936/how-to-color-delimiters) on How to color delimiters in Math Mode, and so I decided to test my LaTeX knowledge by trying to define a new appropriate command: `\leftcolor{color}<delim symbol>` and `\rightcolor{color}<delim symbol>`.

The MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%
\newcommand*\leftcolor[2]{%
 \color{#1}\left#2\normalcolor%
}
\newcommand*\rightcolor[2]{%
 \color{#1}\right#2\normalcolor%
}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
%
\leftcolor{red}(\frac{a}{b}\rightcolor{red})^n \neq \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^n
%
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

The problem can be seen in the result shown below:

> [image]

I clearly see that the exponent positioning is wrong, but I have no clue on how LaTeX puts that symbol in this way, because I followed the only option possible for the correct coloring (even after searching on the `xcolor` documentation I didn't find anything related to this topic).

My guess is that the effective size of the delimiter is "faked" in such a way that the compiler finds more correct to put the exponent as one normal size delimiter rather than the extended one.

I don't know if there is some plain TeX or LaTeX string to help about this situation, because the most common solution in these cases involves the making new delimiters such as:

```
\customdelim{\frac{a}{b}}^n   % these commands are not present in this case
```

The fact is that *I don't request this kind of macro* because I want to be able to switch directly from one color to another as a specific argument.

Comment: I do not have access to a computer at the moment, but does it help to add \yphantom{\left{#2}} after \normalcolor (and the corresponding command for the right delimiter)?

Comment: @malin I tried the code suggested but it gives me an `Undefined Control Sequence` for `\yphantom`, and after trying `\vphantom` the `! Missing delimiter (. inserted)` appears, I'm sorry but LaTeX doesn't want to end this so easily :)

Comment: Typo error :-) does \vphantom{\left#2} work?

Comment: @malin I'm sorry but unfortunately not, as the errmsg is `! Missing delimiter (. inserted)`.

Comment: Try \vphantom{\left( } too, otherwise my ideas are up... :-) interesting problem though!

Comment: @malin The usage of a specific delimiter, in this case `(` in the preamble, gives the same error as before. Maybe I fonud one of DEK allowance valuable bugs :-)

Comment: `\left` and `\right` need to be in the same group. You can’t put only one of them in a `\vphantom`. You could put both in it but then they need also the original content (here the fraction) to actually expand to the right size. The problem here seems to be an internal `\aftergroup\reset@color` which will act as the base for the superscript. But you already use a `\normalsize` after the `\right#2` which will act as a base for the superscript. See `{\frac{a}{b}}^2 = {\frac{a}{b}}\normalcolor^2`

Comment: @ Qrrbrbirlbel The code you suggested showed the difference perfectly (thanks), but I don't really know how to insert this into the macro (I don't yet know the usage of `bgroup`/`egroup` very well).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The macros `\left` and `\right` put their content in its own group.

You will notice this in the following example if you leave out the `\normalcolor` in the `\rightcolor` macro:

```
\leftcolor{blue}( \frac{a}{b} \rightcolor{red})^n
```

The superscript `n` (and everything following it in the same group) turns blue!

The internal macro `\set@color` that is called by `\color` as well as `\normalcolor` contains a `\aftergroup\reset@color` which gets called after the group of `\left` and `\right`. (So the problem is the `\normalcolor` in `\leftcolor` and the `\color` in `\rightcolor`.)
The following `^n` doesn’t see the right math atom to get correctly aligned.

Adding another group around it reverses this affect and `^2` is aligned correctly (see the fractions 4 and 5). But the fact that `\left` and `\right` is an Inner Atom is destroyed hereby, too, as `{}` construct an Ordinary Atom.

TeXbook, page 155:

> There's also an eighth classication, `\mathinner`, which is not normally used for individual symbols; fractions and `\left...\right` constructions are treated as “inner”
>   subformulas, which means that they will be surrounded by additional space in certain circumstances.

The correct usage of re-colored delimiters would need instead of the second group a `\mathinner` to get the correct spacing.

I have implemented this in the `\p` macro that takes an additional optional argument if you want to use different colors for the delimiters.

The difference in spacing is shown with the `a`.

Although it has been said on the linked question, I want to repeat the fact that `\normalcolor` does not switch back to the current color before the `\left` but to the default color. A `\color{green} a \p{red}(){b} c` will still show a black `b` and a green `c`.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\p}[5][]{%
  \edef\@tempa{#1}%
  \ifx\@tempa\@empty
    \edef\@tempa{#2}%
  \fi
  \mathinner{\begingroup\color{\@tempa}\left#3\normalcolor#5\color{#2}\right#4\endgroup}
}
\makeatother
\newcommand*\leftcolor[2]{%
 \color{#1}\left#2\normalcolor%
}
\newcommand*\rightcolor[2]{%
 \color{#1}\right#2%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
a \p{red}(){\frac{a}{b}}^n \\
a \p[blue]{red}(){\frac{a}{b}}^n \\ 
%
a \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^n \\
%
%
a \mathinner{{\leftcolor{blue}( \frac{a}{b} \rightcolor{red})}}^n \\
a \leftcolor{blue}( \frac{a}{b} \rightcolor{red})^n \\ % the 'n' is blue not red!
a {{\leftcolor{blue}( \frac{a}{b} \rightcolor{red})}}^n \\ % the spacing is bad
%
a \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^n
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image] 
[image]

Comment: Thanks, now it works like a charm. Oh but for a last thing: should I use inside the `\newcommand*` `\bgroup\bgroup` and `\egroup\egroup` to obtain the same result in your code? (Maybe it's a silly question, but it will be clear this issue once and for all).

Comment: @AndreaL. What do mean? `{}` is the same as `\bgroup\egroup`. You can use both. By the way, you can define `\p` so that it uses two different colors if you specify two (say with an optional argument).

Comment: it would be better to use a `\begingroup\endgroup` group instead of (two) `{}` groups, to avoid making a mathord

Comment: That definitely cleared my issue, sorry for the last comment but even if it may have seemed obivous it has resolved my problem. Thanks again

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, it would, but it doesn’t correct the superscript. I don’t see a spacing problem compared to the regular fraction. I guess this is related to [Colored symbols](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85033).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: `\left` and `\right` implicitly put the formula including fences in a `\mathinner`. This causes a different spacing, if symbols are before or after the formula. Instead of the two curly braces (or `\bgroup`/`\egroup`) that create two nested `\mathord` formulas, I would use `\mathinner{\begingroup ...\endgroup}`.

Comment: The position of the super script is disturbed by the color whatsit that is inserted after the closing fence to reset the color. The trick of your solution is that the super script is moved from the right delimiter to the whole formula that encloses the color whatsits.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Yes, [so I figured](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125795/defining-a-macro-for-real-colored-delimiters/125802?noredirect=1#comment282471_125795). I have already updated my answer with an explanation and the `\mathinner` solution.

Answer (score 8):

For comparison, ConTeXt provides a `\definemathfence` command for defining colored delimiters. `math-fen.mkiv` predefines a few math fences:

```
\definemathfence [parenthesis] [\c!left=0x28,\c!right=0x29]
\definemathfence [bracket]     [\c!left=0x5B,\c!right=0x5D]
\definemathfence [braces]      [\c!left=0x7B,\c!right=0x7D]
\definemathfence [bar]         [\c!left=0x7C,\c!right=0x7C]
\definemathfence [doublebar]   [\c!left=0x2016,\c!right=0x2016]
\definemathfence [angle]       [\c!left=0x3C,\c!right=0x3E]
```

which you can use using `\fenced[parenthesis]{ \frac {a}{b} }`. To add color, overload one of the predefined fences (or just start from scratch), and add a color attribute as well. For example:

```
\definemathfence[colorbracket][parenthesis][color=red, command=yes]
```

The `command=yes` part defines a command `\colorbracket` that can be used in place of `\fenced[colorbracket]`. Complete example:

```
\definemathfence[colorbracket][parenthesis][color=red, command=yes]

\starttext

\startformula
  \colorbracket{\frac {a}{b}}^n
  \qquad
  \left( \frac {a}{b} \right)^n
\stopformula

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Like all ConTeXt `\define....` commands, you can use `\setup...` command to change the behavior. For example, to change the color from red to blue, you can use:

```
\setupmathfence[colorbracket][color=blue]
```

This command does not support different colors for left and right delimiters. For implementation, see `math-fen.mkiv`.

Comment: When I'll start to look for other typesetting engines like LuaTeX or ConTeX this answer will be very useful (thanks), but now I'd like to put a definitive end to this issue on pdfLaTeX.

Answer (score 3):

After considering the useful comments above (I never imagined that people like [Heiko Oberdiek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967/heiko-oberdiek) would spend their time on my only second question!), I added the implementation of the case where the argument of `color` is expanded from `\@empty` to the standard `black`.

The final MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%
\makeatletter
%
\newcommand\leftcolor[2]{%
  \edef\@tempa{#1}%
  \ifx\@tempa\@empty
    \edef\@tempa{black}%
  \fi
 \mathinner\bgroup\begingroup\color{\@tempa}\left#2\normalcolor%
}
\newcommand\rightcolor[2]{%
  \edef\@tempa{#1}%
  \ifx\@tempa\@empty
    \edef\@tempa{black}%
  \fi
  \color{\@tempa}\right#2\endgroup\egroup%
}
\makeatother
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{gather*}
a\leftcolor{red}(\frac{a}{b} \rightcolor{red})^n \left(\frac{a}{a}\right)^n \\
a\leftcolor{}(\frac{a}{b}\rightcolor{})^n \left(\frac{a}{a}\right)^n \\
a\leftcolor{red}(\frac{a}{b}\rightcolor{blue})^n \left(\frac{a}{a}\right)^n \\
\end{gather*}
%
\end{document}
```

And the final output is now shown correct:

> [image]

I also noticed that the function of `\mathinner\begingroup\bgroup` and `\endgroup\egroup` in each definition makes the code working as `\mathinner{{<argument>}}^n`, but inside my package `LyXbasic` I'll keep the command that [Qrrbrbirlbel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16595/qrrbrbirlbel)  suggested, because the syntax is equally fluid with:

```
\p{<left delim color>}{<right delim color>}{<left delim>}{<right delim>}{<argument>}
```