# inline equation outside margin

Tags: equations, line-breaking, inline

My inline equation falls outside the margin. I was wondering if there is any solution for that? Here is the `MWE`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
where the first equality in \ref{inequality} follows from $\lceil\frac{s}%
{t}\rceil=\lfloor\frac{s+t-1}{t}\rfloor$ for integer $s$ and $t$ and the
inequality follows from the feasibility condition. We also assume that the
item can be ordered at any day of the week and these orders arrive instantly.
For each day $t\in W$ define $p_{x,t,n,j} \left(
\text{for all }x=0,\cdots,u_{j}\text{ }\text{and }
n\in N_{x,t,j}
\right)$ to be the joint probability of
\end{document}
```

Comment: Stuff enclosed in `\left...\right` can't be broken, so you're giving the paragraph formatter an impossible problem to solve. Either (a) use a displayed formula or (b) leave out `\left` and `\right` or (c) use `\raggedright`.

Comment: … (d) without braces at all, (dd) `$p_{x,t,n,j}$ for all $x=0,\cdots,u_{j}$ and $n\in N_{x,t,j}$`, (e) combining (dd) and text braces. (Note, that your `\left(` hasn't a space preceding it.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution is to use the `\bracr` macro as below:

[image]

or as **Stephan Lehmke** suggested, use display math:

[image]

### References:

- [How to compute exact width added by \left. \right](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54023/how-to-compute-exact-width-added-by-left-right)

### CodeL

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,showframe]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\def\@BracContents{} % default (used by \suchthat)
\newcommand{\BracKern}{\kern-\nulldelimiterspace}
\newcommand{\@Brac}[3]{% #1,#3 = left/right bracket type
    \ensuremath{%
        \begingroup\def\@BracContents{#2}%
        \mathopen{\left#1\vphantom{#2}\BracKern\right.}% left bracket
        #2%  content
        \mathclose{\left.\BracKern\vphantom{#2}\right#3}% right bracket
        \endgroup%
    }%
}
\newcommand{\bracr}[1]{\@Brac{(}{#1}{)}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Use macro:}
where the first equality in \ref{inequality} follows from $\lceil\frac{s}%
{t}\rceil=\lfloor\frac{s+t-1}{t}\rfloor$ for integer $s$ and $t$ and the
inequality follows from the feasibility condition. We also assume that the
item can be ordered at any day of the week and these orders arrive instantly.
For each day $t\in W$ define $p_{x,t,n,j} \bracr{
\text{for all }x=0,\cdots,u_{j}\text{ }\text{and }
n\in N_{x,t,j}
}$ to be the joint probability of

\section{Display Math:}
where the first equality in \ref{inequality} follows from $\lceil\frac{s}%
{t}\rceil=\lfloor\frac{s+t-1}{t}\rfloor$ for integer $s$ and $t$ and the
inequality follows from the feasibility condition. We also assume that the
item can be ordered at any day of the week and these orders arrive instantly.
For each day $t\in W$ define 
\[
p_{x,t,n,j} \left(
\text{for all }x=0,\cdots,u_{j}\text{ }\text{and }
n\in N_{x,t,j}
\right)
\]
to be the joint probability of
\end{document}
```

Comment: For future reference: I used solution suggested by @egreg (solution). But for situations where egreg's solution don't apply, solution suggested by @ Peter works perfectly fine. Actually Peter's solution is more general.

Comment: Can you clarify why we need to use the macro instead of `\raggedleft` combined with `\raggedright`?

Comment: Your first solution does not work for some equations like $P = \min ( 1,{\rm e}^{-\beta [U(\vec{r'})- U(\vec{r})] }  )$. More details here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/596051/inline-equations-go-off-margin

Answer (score 4):

The way you input the formula is questionable. Here is how I'd type it:

```
For each day $t\in W$ define $p_{x,t,n,j}$ (for all $x=0$,~\dots, $u_{j}$
and $n\in N_{x,t,j}$) to be the joint probability of
```

Those parentheses are *not* math and shouldn't be larger than usual. You are simply stating a side condition, just use alternating text and math.

Comment: Very good point @egreg. I fixed it.