# Bracing fraction numerator or denominator to the left or right

Tags: math-mode, braces, fractions

I have a fraction with further fractions in both the numerator and denominator. I wish to label the fractions in the numerator and denominator with braces to the right. I would like these braces to span the full height of the fractions but I would not like them to extend the fraction line any further.

I have tried `\frac{a}{\left.\frac{b}{c}\right}}` which achieves the former but not the latter and I have tried `\frac{a}{\frac{b}{c}\mathrlap{\}}}` which achieves the latter but not the former, since I can't put one half of the `\left` `\right` pair inside `\mathrlap` and the other half outside.

Comment: How often do you need this construction? If it's a one time thing you could simply use `\big`,`\Big`,... e.g. `\frac{a}{\frac{b}{c}\mathrlap{\big\}}}`

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps what you are looking for is a combination of `\mathrlap` and `\smash` which is what is incorporated in the `\BraceRight` and `\BraceLeft` macros.

[image]

However, as HendrikVogt pointed out,
this requires that there be manual spacing added afterwards if there is text that follows it.
To alleviate this issue I have defined two more macros `\FracBraceBottomRight` and `\FracBraceBottomLeft` which also add the approriate `\hptantom` after or before the fraction.

[image]

One downside of this this is that you need a different macro in case you desire further options (such as optional braces around either side of the numerator. This can be fixed with a better interface to enable/disable the appropriate brace, but I think that that is more of a question of coming up with the better UI.

### References:

- The `\BracKern` is to adjust for the horizontal space inserted by the `\left.`, `\right.` as per [How to compute exact width added by \left. \right](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54023/how-to-compute-exact-width-added-by-left-right)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand*{\BraceRight}[1]{#1\mathrlap{\smash{\left.\vphantom{#1}\right\}}}}%
\newcommand*{\BraceLeft}[1]{\mathllap{\smash{\left\{\vphantom{#1}\right.}}#1}%

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54023/how-to-compute-exact-width-added-by-left-right
\newcommand{\BracKern}{\kern-\nulldelimiterspace}
\newcommand*{\FracBraceBottomRight}[2]{%
    \frac{#1}{#2\mathrlap{\smash{\left.\BracKern\vphantom{#2}\right\}}}}%
    \hphantom{\left.\vphantom{#2}\right\}}%
}%
\newcommand*{\FracBraceBottomLeft}[2]{%
    \hphantom{\left\{\vphantom{#2}\right.\BracKern}%
    \frac{#1}{\mathllap{\smash{\left\{\vphantom{#2}\right.}}#2}%
}%

\begin{document}
Requires manual spacing:

$\frac{a}{\frac{b}{c}}$\quad%
$\frac{a}{\BraceLeft{\frac{b}{c}}}$\quad%
$\frac{a}{\BraceRight{\frac{b}{c}}}$

\bigskip
Auto spacing with \verb|\hphantom|:

$\FracBraceBottomRight{a}{\frac{b}{c}}$%
$\FracBraceBottomRight{a}{\frac{b}{c}}$%
$\FracBraceBottomLeft{a}{\frac{b}{c}}$%
$\FracBraceBottomLeft{a}{\frac{b}{c}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that the brace will produce an overlap with material after the fraction.

Comment: @HendrikVogt: Yep just noticed that when doing the macro verion. Best fix I can think of is to have a macro that accepts the numerator and denominator of the fraction as paramaters and then adds the brace with an appropriate `\hphantom` following. But, for the general case, this would require numerous different macros depending on if you perhaps wanted the brace on the `top/bottom`, `left/right` or any combinations of these.  Of course there is _always_ the `tikz` way. :-)

Comment: Yep, you'll need an appropriate `\hphantom` after the fraction.