# reading through the definition of `\cfrac` in AMSMath

Tags: amsmath, fractions

I am reading through the definition of `\cfrac` in [AMSMath](http://www.ams.org/publications/authors/tex/amslatex)...

```
\newcommand{\cfrac}[3][c]{{\displaystyle\frac{%
  \strut\ifx r#1\hfill\fi#2\ifx l#1\hfill\fi}{#3}}%
  \kern-\nulldelimiterspace}
```

Can someone explain a bit how this code works?  Immediately see the [`newcommand`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1050/whats-the-difference-between-newcommand-and-newcommand)  used to define `\cfrac` and that it take three arguments.  I don't know what `[c]` means here.

Then onto the main portion.  Continued Fractions are presented [display style](https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=LaTeX:Math#Display_Style_.28.5Cdisplaystyle.29).  However,

- can someone explain to me how `l#1` and `r#1` are used? they look like conditionals
- I checked that `#2` and `#3` correspond to the **numerator** and **denominator**

I can sort of distinguish the important parts

```
{{\displaystyle
\frac{ \strut
    \ifx r#1\hfill\fi
    #2
    \ifx l#1\hfill\fi}
{#3}} 
\kern-\nulldelimiterspace}
```

Then if I replace #2 with A and #3 with B I get a nice fraction... just like `\frac{A}{B}`

`\ifx` is always followed by the backwards-if `\fi`  -- then what are the conditionals `r#1` and `l#`?

and what is the rule of `\strut` ?

---

There is discussion of `\kern` and `\nulldelimiterspace` in other parts of this site

[How to compute exact width added by \left. \right](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54023/how-to-compute-exact-width-added-by-left-right)

Comment: `\newcommand{\cfrac}[3][c]` means three arguments, the first of which is optional, defaulting to `c`, when not provided in square brackets.  Indeed, `\ifx l#1` and `\ifx r#1` are comparisons of whether left or right alignment has been specified as the optional first argument.  Try and compare `$\cfrac[l]{x}{v^2}$

$\cfrac[c]{x}{v^2}$

$\cfrac[r]{x}{v^2}$`

Comment: `\ifx` compares the next two tokens, without expansion.  A `\strut` is a zero-width character that extends vertically from the allocated character depth to the allocated character height.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
\newcommand{\cfrac}[3][c]{...
```

defines a command with two mandatory arguments and one optional so the use is `\cfrac{a}{b}` or `\cfrac[r]{a}{b}` with the former being equivalent to `\cfrac[c]{a}{b}`.

`\ifx` is a tex primitive which tests the following two tokens so if `#1` (the value of the optional argument) is `r` then

```
\ifx r#1
```

is true so `\hfill` is added, otherwise control jumps to `\fi`.

so

`\cfrac[r]{a}{b}` is `\frac{\strut\hfill a}{b}`

`\cfrac[c]{a}{b}` is `\frac{\strut a}{b}`

`\cfrac[l]{a}{b}` is `\frac{\strut a \hfill}{b}`

each in `\displaystyle` and followed by a negative space of `\kern-\nulldelimiterspace`

For completeness, the other commands

A `\strut` is an invisible zero-width rule (with height `0.7\baselineskip` and depth `0.3\baselineskip`) designed to fill out a normal line spacing. This ensures the numerator is given the same vertical space whether the numerator is `a` or `A` the same technique is used to give consistent spacing in matrices.

`\displaystyle` gives the more open style normally used in display equations such as `\begin{equation}` rather than inline math from `$`

`\nulldelimiterspace` is the space that you get from the "missing delimiter" in constructs such as `\left\{xxxx\right.` but also in particular it is added either side of fraction constructs, this allows cfrac to always have close spacing on the right hand side, as needed for continuous fractions.

The following example has exaggerated setting of `\nulldelimiterspace` to show the effect.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\nulldelimiterspace=10pt
$|\cfrac{a}{bbb}|$


$|\cfrac[l]{a}{bbb}|$


$|\cfrac[r]{a}{bbb}|$

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. You may want to add an explanation of what `\strut` is doing.

Comment: @Mico better? :-)

Comment: I've added a parenthetical remark with information about the dimensions of `\strut`. :-) Feel free to revert...

Comment: @Mico not better enough I see :-)